# Can SQL calculate aggregate functions across multiple tables?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have two existing tables, "dogs" and "cats":

```
 dog_name | owner
 ---------+------
 Sparky   | Bob
 Rover    | Bob
 Snoopy   | Chuck
 Odie     | Jon

 cat_name | owner
 ---------+------
 Garfield | Jon
 Muffy    | Sam
 Stupid   | Bob
```

How do I write a query with this output?

```
 owner | num_dogs | num_cats
 ------+----------+---------
 Bob   |     2    |    1
 Chuck |     1    |    0
 Sam   |     0    |    1
 Jon   |     1    |    1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select owner, sum(num_dogs), sum(num_cats) from
  (select owner, 1 as num_dogs, 0 as num_cats from dogs
   union
   select owner, 0 as num_dogs, 1 as num_cats from cats)
group by owner
```

Answer (score 6):

I prefer this one:

```
select owner
     , count(dog_name) dogs
     , count(cat_name) cats
  from cats FULL OUTER JOIN dogs ON (cats.owner = dogs.owner)
```

Comment: This is missing a `GROUP BY owner` clause, and you'll have to qualify your `owner` column

Answer (score 3):

In T-SQL for SQL Server 2005 (replace the CTE with an inline subquery if not):

```
WITH ownership AS (
    SELECT owner, COUNT(dog_name) AS num_dogs, 0 AS num_cats -- counts all non-NULL dog_name
    FROM dogs
    GROUP BY owner

    UNION

    SELECT owner, 0 AS num_dogs, COUNT(cat_name) as num_cats -- counts all non-NULL cat_name
    FROM cats
    GROUP BY owner
)
SELECT ownership.owner
    ,SUM(ownership.num_dogs) AS num_dogs
    ,SUM(ownership.num_cats) as num_cats
FROM ownership
GROUP BY ownership.owner
```

Answer (score 1):

I started with Cade Roux's excellent answer, but changed the WITH...AS () to use a table variable, as I am ended up using the results from a similar query for further aggregate functions.

```
-- Table variable declaration
DECLARE @RainingCatsDogs TABLE
(
    Owner nvarchar(255),
    num_cats int,
    num_dogs int
)

-- Populate the table variable with data from the union of the two SELECT statements
INSERT INTO @RainingCatsDogs

-- Get the count of doggies
SELECT 
    owner, COUNT(dog_name) AS num_dogs, 0 AS num_cats
FROM 
    dogs
GROUP BY 
    owner

-- join the results from the two SELECT statements
UNION

-- Get the count of kittehs
SELECT 
    owner, 0 AS num_dogs, COUNT(cat_name) as num_cats
FROM 
    cats
GROUP BY 
    owner

-- From the table variable, you can calculate the summed results
SELECT
    owner,
    SUM(num_dogs),
    SUM(num_cats)
FROM 
    @RainingCatsDogs
```

Answer (score 1):

If your database can handle it, I'd double down on [FerranB's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/319355/521799) and write a geeky [`NATURAL FULL JOIN`](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/03/07/impress-your-coworkers-with-a-sql-natural-full-outer-join/) solution. I mean, when was the last time you got the chance to do so?

```sql
SELECT owner, COUNT(dog_name), COUNT(cat_name)
FROM cats 
NATURAL FULL JOIN dogs
GROUP BY owner
```

Comment: Honestly, never :)