# Aggregate function across two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need for further working routine a query which calculates several functions across two (maybe more) tables. But once I import more than one table I got odd results caused by JOIN conditions. First I used that query:

```
SELECT
sum(s.bedarf2050_kwh_a) AS bedarf_kWh_a, 
sum(s.bedarf2050_kwh_a)*0.2 AS netzverlust,
sum(s.bedarf2050_kwh_a) + sum(s.bedarf2050_kwh_a)*0.2 AS gesamtbedarf,
sum(pv.modulflaeche_qm) AS instbar_modulflaeche_qm

FROM 
siedlungsareale_wbm s, pv_st_potenziale_gis pv

WHERE 
s.vg_solar LIKE '%NWS 2%' 
AND 
ST_Covers(s.geom, pv.geom);
```

Using sum with DISTINCT returns some accurate values but only if all input values are unique. That's not a solution I can use:

```
SELECT 
SUM(DISTINCT s.bedarf2050_kwh_a) AS bedarf_kWh_a,
SUM(DISTINCT s.bedarf2050_kwh_a)*0.2 AS netzverlust,
SUM(DISTINCT s.bedarf2050_kwh_a) + SUM(DISTINCT s.bedarf2050_kwh_a)*0.2 AS gesamtbedarf,
SUM(pv.modulflaeche_qm) AS instbar_modulflaeche_qm,
(SUM(DISTINCT s.bedarf2050_kwh_a) + SUM(DISTINCT s.bedarf2050_kwh_a)*0.2)*0.01499 AS startwert_speichergroesse

FROM
siedlungsareale_wbm s, pv_st_potenziale_gis pv

WHERE
pv.vg_solar LIKE '%NWS 2%'

AND
ST_Covers(s.geom, pv.geom);
```

DISTINCT would be a proper solution if the DISTINCT refers to another column, not the column to use in the function. Or some subquery or other JOIN condition. But all I tried run in errors or false result values.

I found some solutions using UNION dealing with aggregate function on multiple tables. But as I tried to fit the code on my query I got errors.

For example like there:
[Can SQL calculate aggregate functions across multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319262/can-sql-calculate-aggregate-functions-across-multiple-tables)

Hope someone can help me to build a working query for my task.

[EDIT] simple example

siedlungsareale

```
id | bedarf2050_kWh_a | a | b | c | vg_solar | geom
---|------------------|---|---|---|----------|-----
1  |               20 |   |   |   | NWS 2    | xxxxx
2  |               10 |   |   |   | NWS 2    | xxxxx
3  |               30 |   |   |   | NWS 2    | xxxxx
4  |                5 |   |   |   | NWS 2    | xxxxx
5  |               15 |   |   |   | NWS 2    | xxxxx

sum = 80
```

pv_st_potenziale_gis

```
id |  modulflaeche_qm | x | y | z | geom
---|------------------|---|---|---|---------
1  |            10    |   |   |   | xxxxx
2  |            10    |   |   |   | xxxxx
3  |            20    |   |   |   | xxxxx
4  |            10    |   |   |   | xxxxx
5  |            30    |   |   |   | xxxxx
6  |            30    |   |   |   | xxxxx
7  |            10    |   |   |   | xxxxx
8  |            10    |   |   |   | xxxxx
9  |            10    |   |   |   | xxxxx
10 |            10    |   |   |   | xxxxx

sum = 140


SELECT sum(s.bedarfxxxx) AS bedarf, sum(pv.mflaeche) As mflaeche
FROM siedlungsareale s, pv_st_potenziale_gis pv
WHERE s.vg_solar LIKE '%NWS 2%' AND ST_Covers(s.geom,pv.geom);
```

Expected correct result:

```
bedarf   | mflaeche
---------|----------
      80 |      140
```

There I would get the sum of all values for column 'bedarf' from 'siedlungsareale' and all for 'mflaeche' from 'pv_st_potenziale_gis'

But the real calculated values of column 'bedarf' using this query are much higher caused of the CROSS JOIN condition.

And the other query:

```
SELECT sum(DISTINCT s.bedarfxxxx) AS bedarf, sum(DISTINCT pv.mflaeche) As mflaeche
FROM siedlungsareale s, pv_st_potenziale_gis pv
WHERE s.vg_solar LIKE '%NWS 2%' AND ST_Covers(s.geom,pv.geom);
```

returns:

```
bedarf   | mflaeche
---------|-----------
     80  |      60
```

Accurate value for 'bedarf' caused the values are unique. But for mflaeche where some values occurre several times the result is wrong.

Comment: could you create simple example input and desired output? Yes, I can do it by myself to illustrate how you have to aggregate joined tables, but after all, it's you question.

Comment: Can't you write something like "select someid, sum(...) from table1 t1 left join (select someid, sum(...) from table2 group by someid) t2 on t2.someid = t1.someid"? This way you group second results before joining and avoid multiplying. Using DISTINCT is clearly wrong approach.

Comment: "DISTINCT would be a proper solution if the DISTINCT refers to another column, not the column to use in the function." Make use of group by for the other column that you want the aggregate function to be operated on.

Comment: Have you checked - without aggregating - that your JOIN condition ST_Covers(...) actually yields the right set of tuples (when using SELECT *)

Comment: Thing is, I don't want to group my results in any way. The only desired output should be one line with the aggregated calculations

Comment: @FabianBüttner Yes, the selection by ST_Covers is the right one. I tried also by giving these table the string expression 'NWS 2', too. Result is the same.

Comment: @nunatak So, you do not get repetitions when you just do SELECT *? The columns sum up to 80 and 60? I would expect that you have repetitions because the join does not relate tuples stricly one-to-one.

Comment: Sure, for table 1 (Think because it's the shorter table) I got many repetition êntries.