# Get users order by data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I want to get a list of users  order by two sets of data:

1. number of posts
2. number of stars (favorites)

For this I'm using two tables:

**favorites**

```
|user_id|post_id|
 10       2
 10       3
 15       1
```

**posts**

```
|post_id|author_id|
 1        10
 2        28
 3        15
```

For this I'm using the following mysql query:

```
SELECT posts.user_id
     , COUNT(posts.id) as posts
     , COUNT(favorites.id) as stars 
  FROM forge.posts 
  JOIN favorites 
    ON posts.user_id = favorites.author_id 
 group 
    by posts.user_id 
 order 
    by posts desc
     , stars desc;
```

Result:

```
|user_id|posts|stars|
 10      2     2
 15      1     1
```

The order of the resulting list is not reflecting the reality.

The problem with this query is that is returning returning the number of `posts = posts*results from favorites` and `stars = stars*results from posts`.
While I understand why is this happening but I don't know how to make it return "distinct" COUNT results for both `posts` and `stars`.

Comment: I'd go step by step and first query each on its own and then use union. If I understand correctly this is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319262/can-sql-calculate-aggregate-functions-across-multiple-tables

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query