Selecting SUM and COUNT of children of an aggregate SQL statement
Background
I'm working on an interface that displays aggregated statistics of user behavior linked to promotional campaigns. The database used to store these actions is ClickHouse (for the sake of large scale aggregate statistics). As far as I can tell the query syntax can emulate regular MySQL very closely.
The relevant tables look like this:
page_visit_actions

promotion_id
action_type
campaign_id
...

purchases

promotion_id
price
campaign_id
...

The Task
I need to display number of certain actions performed as aggregated by an arbitrary column in the page_visit_actions table. That could be for example the number of product shares aggregated by  promotion or by date.
Minimal setup
CREATE TABLE page_visit_actions (
    promotion_id VARCHAR(100),
    action_type VARCHAR(100),
    campaign_id int UNSIGNED
);

CREATE TABLE purchases (
    promotion_id VARCHAR(100),
    price FLOAT(10, 2),
    campaign_id int UNSIGNED
);


INSERT INTO page_visit_actions (promotion_id, action_type, campaign_id) VALUES ('5ac4ea14-f157-45a0-a706-765f4c624920', 'share_product', 17);
INSERT INTO page_visit_actions (promotion_id, action_type, campaign_id) VALUES ('5ac4ea14-f157-45a0-a706-765f4c624920', 'add_product_to_favorites', 17);
INSERT INTO page_visit_actions (promotion_id, action_type, campaign_id) VALUES ('7140beb4-5fc9-46b1-9790-0b580b6c83f3', 'add_product_to_favorites', 17);
INSERT INTO page_visit_actions (promotion_id, action_type, campaign_id) VALUES ('97a207e6-c9f8-4edf-8f9f-397544c790b9', 'add_product_to_favorites', 17);

INSERT INTO purchases (promotion_id, price, campaign_id) VALUES ('5ac4ea14-f157-45a0-a706-765f4c624920', 15.0, 17);
INSERT INTO purchases (promotion_id, price, campaign_id) VALUES ('5ac4ea14-f157-45a0-a706-765f4c624920', 5.0, 17);
INSERT INTO purchases (promotion_id, price, campaign_id) VALUES ('97a207e6-c9f8-4edf-8f9f-397544c790b9', 5.0, 17);

Queries
I started out with this simple aggregate query to get the actions for each promotion:
select 
promotion_id, 
count(*) as total, 
sum(case when action_type = 'share_product' then 1 else 0 end) as share, 
sum(case when action_type = 'add_product_to_favorites' then 1 else 0 end) as favorite, 
sum(case when action_type = 'add_product_to_basket' then 1 else 0 end) as basket 
from page_visit_actions
group by promotion_id;

The query works as expected:
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
| promotion_id                         | total | share | favorite | basket |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
| 5ac4ea14-f157-45a0-a706-765f4c624920 |     2 |     1 |        1 |      0 |
| 7140beb4-5fc9-46b1-9790-0b580b6c83f3 |     1 |     0 |        1 |      0 |
| 97a207e6-c9f8-4edf-8f9f-397544c790b9 |     1 |     0 |        1 |      0 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+

Problem
However, I ran into a problem when I was asked to add the total amount of purchases and revenue for the aggregated statistics and tried the following query:
select 
page_visit_actions.promotion_id, 
count(page_visit_actions.promotion_id) as total, 
sum(case when action_type = 'share_product' then 1 else 0 end) as share, 
sum(case when action_type = 'add_product_to_favorites' then 1 else 0 end) as favorite, 
sum(case when action_type = 'add_product_to_basket' then 1 else 0 end) as basket,
count(purchases.promotion_id) as purchases,
sum(purchases.price) as revenue
from page_visit_actions
left join purchases on page_visit_actions.promotion_id=purchases.promotion_id
group by page_visit_actions.promotion_id;

I can use the column promotion_id that is common to both page_visit_actions and purchases to join the tables, but this has the side effect of messing up the count statistics because multiple actions can refer to the same promotion (promotions are given on per user basis but the user can both share and favorite the promotion, resulting in 2 actions referencing same promotion) so the same purchase ends up getting joined to multiple actions.
Therefore, my attempted to query results in:
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
| promotion_id                         | total | share | favorite | basket | purchases | revenue |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
| 5ac4ea14-f157-45a0-a706-765f4c624920 |     4 |     2 |        2 |      0 |         4 |   40.00 |
| 7140beb4-5fc9-46b1-9790-0b580b6c83f3 |     1 |     0 |        1 |      0 |         0 |    NULL |
| 97a207e6-c9f8-4edf-8f9f-397544c790b9 |     1 |     0 |        1 |      0 |         1 |    5.00 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+

However, the correct statistics would look like this:
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
| promotion_id                         | total | share | favorite | basket | purchases | revenue |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
| 5ac4ea14-f157-45a0-a706-765f4c624920 |     2 |     1 |        1 |      0 |         2 |   20.00 |
| 7140beb4-5fc9-46b1-9790-0b580b6c83f3 |     1 |     0 |        1 |      0 |         0 |    NULL |
| 97a207e6-c9f8-4edf-8f9f-397544c790b9 |     1 |     0 |        1 |      0 |         1 |    5.00 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+

Question
How do I query the count() and sum() of children (purchases) related to aggregated table (page_visit_actions) without messing up the original aggregate group statistics?

Sample data and expected results would help immensely. It sounds like you might need to pre-aggregate promotions before joining it.

Thank you for the suggestion and interest. It's getting relatively late for me so I will try to add more relevant information tomorrow.

@Charlieface I added the relevant details reproducing a minimal testing setup as well as the actual queries I used for testing, their results and the expected result.
Note that promotions is not actually a table in the statistics database since the promotion_id values come from an external system.

Each table shows multiple records for a promotion_id. Build two aggregate queries then join those queries. One of the queries could be treated as 'master' or join both to a dataset that has unique promotion_id.

You need to aggregate the two tables separately, as they each have a one-to-many relationship with promotion (which you haven't shown).
It is a common mistake in aggregation queries to just join everything together and aggregate afterwards. That gets you the wrong results, as you end up with a cartesian join between all the child tables.
select 
  pva.*,
  p.purchases,
  p.revenue
from (
    select
      pva.promotion_id,
      count(*) as count_actions,
      count(case when pva.action_type = 'share_product' then 1 end) as share,
      count(case when pva.action_type = 'add_product_to_favorites' then 1 end) as favorite,
      count(case when pva.action_type = 'add_product_to_basket' then 1 end) as basket
    from page_visit_actions pva
    group by
      pva.promotion_id
) pva
left join (
    select
      p.promotion_id,
      count(*) as purchases,
      sum(p.price) as revenue
    from purchases p
    group by
      p.promotion_id
) p on pva.promotion_id = p.promotion_id;

db<>fiddle
Given that you probably have promotions which have neither page_visit_actions nor purchases, or one without the other, you probably want to start with the promotions table and left-join everything else, again pre-aggregating.
select
  pm.*,
  pva.*,
  p.purchases,
  p.revenue
from promotions pm
left join (
    select
      pva.promotion_id,
      count(*) as count_actions,
      count(case when pva.action_type = 'share_product' then 1 end) as share,
      count(case when pva.action_type = 'add_product_to_favorites' then 1 end) as favorite,
      count(case when pva.action_type = 'add_product_to_basket' then 1 end) as basket
    from page_visit_actions pva
    group by
      pva.promotion_id
) pva on pva.promotion_id = pm.id
left join (
    select
      p.promotion_id,
      count(*) as purchases,
      sum(p.price) as revenue
    from purchases p
    group by
      p.promotion_id
) p on p.promotion_id = pm.id;


Thank you for your answer. Regarding promotions, they don't actually have a table in the database like I mentioned in one of the comments on the question.

Still have to aggregate each dataset then either join to each other (if one can serve as 'master') or to a dataset that has all promotion_id as unique values. Or try UNION approach shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319262/can-sql-calculate-aggregate-functions-across-multiple-tables.

The first SQL provides desired output for given sample data.

Maybe use FULL OUTER JOIN between the two aggregate queries.

Was thinking that, but OP's original query used left join and I'm not going to change that

Apologies for getting back to this so late. While the solution is workable when aggregating by promotion_id, it doesn't seem viable when the aggregation needs to be done with a key which only exists on one of the tables. I'm supposed to be able to aggregate by any column of page_visit_actions but most of those columns do not exists on the purchases table.
I understand that this was missing from the minimal setup example but actions can also have other columns like user_browser and the UI should be able to aggregate by any of these while including purchases in the result.

Well you need some sort of join column, otherwise there is no way of correlating the results. You'd need to give a proper example, maybe create a new question for that. If data can be present in either table (and not just that you always need data in page_visit_actions) then you may want a full join

Ideally, promotion_id could be still be used to join page_visit_actions and purchases together but I'm not sure if that's possible when another column is used to aggregate page_visit_actions.

I guess you can aggregate again maybe in an outer query? It's really hard to say without a fuller explanation of the relationships between the tables. What would be the sample data and expected results? Please show inn a new question.

I made a db fiddle with the updated data.
It seems like a waste to copy-paste the almost exact same question. Only the column used to aggregate changes but the same expected and actual result remain.

So is it strictly the case that user_browser and promotion_id are functionally dependent? So group them up again, something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/abLoKUJm If they are not functionally dependent then It's not clear to me how you would join it up. That's why I asked for a new set of sample data, showing all the edge cases and explaining the exact logic desired.
